# Different method to retrieve image from excel via vb.net

Tags: excel, vb.net, winforms

I am currently retreiving the images via the clipboard, is there any other methods to retrieve the images to a picturebox on an winform application?  Here's my current code:

```
Dim img As Image
Dim xlsApp1 As Object
Dim xlsWB As Object
Dim xlsSheet As Object
xlsApp1 = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlsWB = xlsApp1.Workbooks
xlsApp1.DisplayAlerts = False
xlsWB.Open("myexcel")
xlsSheet = xlsApp1.ActiveSheet

For Each xlsShape As Excel.Shape In xlsSheet.Shapes
    xlsShape.Copy()
    If xlsShape.Name = "Picture 1" Then
        'process the image
         img = Clipboard.GetImage 'where i get my image but want a different way?
    End If
next
```

Comment: *"Reason I want another method is the clipboard is giving me issues that I would rather not have to deal with"* - can you elaborate on what those issues are?

Comment: Right now your question is essentially "I have a problem that I want a solution for but I don't want to say what that problem is". At this point no one can help you, and this question won't gather any traction/will be closed for "Unclear what you are asking".

Comment: @dwirony I've changed my description.

Comment: Your question has only become more ambiguous - I would suggest completely re-posting your question with a clear, outlined problem so that we can help you :).

Comment: what's so ambiguous about my question? "is there any other methods to retrieve the images to a picturebox on an winform application?"